# ngClass not changing on Route Event

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, styles

i have a bottomNavigation that tells in which route we are clicking by changing theyr style.

Here is my template of the bottom-navigation template

```
  class="menu-icon"

  [ngClass]="{ 'active-item': buttonActivated.value == '/my-goal'}"

  [ngClass]="{ 'active-item': buttonActivated.value == '/my-goal/goal-detail'}"
>
```

Here is my TS file

```
 buttonActivated: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('/')
 
 constructor(private router: Router) {

 this.router.events.subscribe(() => {

  this.buttonActivated.next(this.router.url);
} }
```

So the logic is: everytime the route changes or have an event, the `buttonActivated.value` will change.
And depending on that value the ngClass would change to `active-item`.

When i click to `/my-goal` route the ngClass works perfectly, but when i click in his child `/my-goal/goal-detail/id` and when i come back in the same route, the ngClass is not working as a `active-item`.

I checked the value of `buttonActivated.value` and is changing correctly when i click back on the parent route, but the ngClass is still not changing.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you set the `routerLink` directly on your buttons? If yes, have you taken a look into `routerLinkActive` directive (https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)? This way you wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus no i dont add it on the button, i make the change with a special css styling

Comment: @FabianStrathaus the code works, but when i go in the child route of the '/my-goal' and come back to '/my-goal' the ngClass is not affecting the change

Answer (score 2):

You can use [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) directive.

RouterLinkActive directive add the `.active` class by tracking either the linked route of element is currently active or not, and then allow to specify CSS as per needed.

Comment: As i mentioned, i am using a different way which works the same way, the problem is when i come back to that route and the style is not aplied